# Text Node comes out of the ScrollPane range when apply rotate

Tags: javafx, scrollpane, rotatetransform

Unrecognized problem.

When try to apply rotate and `setLayout` outside of the `ScrollPane` range, a portion of the text appears on the `anchorPaneForScene`, and even when scrolling, the text remains static

It will be clearer in code and images

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class example extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    AnchorPane anchorPaneForScene=new AnchorPane();

    ScrollPane scrollPane=new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setLayoutY(100);
    scrollPane.setPrefSize(300,300);

    anchorPaneForScene.getChildren().add(scrollPane);

    Scene scene=new Scene(anchorPaneForScene,800,500);

    AnchorPane anchorPaneForScroll=new AnchorPane();
    anchorPaneForScroll.setPrefSize(400,800);

    scrollPane.setContent(anchorPaneForScroll);

    Text text=new Text("JAVAFX");

    Rotate rotate=new Rotate();
    rotate.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    rotate.setAngle(-30);

    scrollPane.setContent(anchorPaneForScroll);

    anchorPaneForScroll.getChildren().add(text);

    text.getTransforms().add(rotate);
    text.setFont(Font.font(80));
    text.setLayoutY(30);
    text.setLayoutX(30);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
 }
}
```

Output

[image: Output]

When scrolling
[image: When scrolling]

Comment: Rotation around anything but the z-axis (i.e. a rotation that results in change of z coordinates) is problematic for 2D objects. `PerspectiveTransform` may be an alternative.

Comment: `PerspectiveTransform`  needs Group ,Is there a better solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, `PerspectiveTransform` is experiencing the same problem!!

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove the rotate when applying PerspectiveTransform, it works, thank you for the alternative.